# seeing lot of CLOSE_WAIT with okhttp 3.81

Tags: tomcat, okhttp

seeing lot of CLOSE_WAIT connections on ubuntu when I execute the below command where 20919 is the pid of tomcat. Does lot of sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state cause high number of open files ?

sudo lsof -p 20919 | grep CLOSE_WAIT

below is the code to close the client requests

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

    String webServiceEndPoint = url;
    Response response =null;
    if (!url.matches("^(http|https)://.*$")) {
        webServiceEndPoint = backendConfig.getWebServiceUri().concat(url);
    }

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(webServiceEndPoint)
            .method(method, getRequestBody(requestContext, method))
            .headers(buildHeaders(headerBuilder))
            .build();

    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody = response.body().string();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (isJsonObject(responseBody)) {
                callback.onSuccess(JsonObjectBuilder.fromString(responseBody));
            } else if (isJsonArray(responseBody)) {
                callback.onSuccess(JsonObjectBuilder.arrayfromString(responseBody));
            } else {
               // logger.debug("couldn't determine response type [response : {}]", responseBody);
                callback.onSuccess(responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            callback.onError(responseBody, new SimpleStatusLine(response.code(), ""));
        }
        if(response!=null)response.body().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        callback.onFailure(e);
    }finally{
        LOG.debug("finally cleaning rsources");
        if(response!=null)response.body().close();
        client.connectionPool().evictAll();
    }
```

This does not seem to clean up the CLOSE_WAIT state. I am using tomcat 8 with Okhttp 3.8.1

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT explained: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/janelewis/2010/03/09/explaining-close_wait/

Comment: I understand close wait but I want to isolate what is causing it. I see rest call is made and service returns results closing db connections. Client code I have posted above. Want to know what is causing this issue

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311

Comment: @LuisMuñoz am using response.body().close() in the finally block as shown in the code I posted